# Pushing strings onto the beginning and end of an array created during for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Right now I have for loop that is returning an array with the numbers 1 - 90, but am having trouble replacing the numbers 1 and 90 with the strings stored in my variables far and close (respectively).

```
const far = "01/01/20"
const close = "03/01/20"


const pushNinetyDays = () => {
    let arr = [];
             for (i = 1; i <= 90 ; i++) {
              arr.push(i)
           } 
     return arr
 } 

// => [1, 2, 3, 4,...89, 90]
```

I tried something along these lines for awhile, but wasn't getting the correct result.

```
const pushNinetyDays = () => {
    let arr = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= 90 ; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 1) {
            arr.push(far) 
         } else if (arr[i] === 90) {
            arr.push(close)
         } else {
            arr.push(i)
         } 
    }
     return arr
 }

// still returning this array => [ 1, 2, 3, 4,...89,90] 
// when i'm looking for this array => ["01,01,20", 2, 3, 4...89, "03/01/20"]
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you need to find these in the array? Because if not, you don't need to loop over it again - you *know* which indexes are the start and end of the array. It's the first and the last index.

Comment: What do you mean by find them in the array? I need to be able to update these specific indices in the array with data i'm getting from an API, then use the array for another purpose.

Comment: You are looping over the array trying to find the first and last element currently. Yet you don't need to loop and search for them. To replace them directly you just do `arr[0] = "first"` and `arr[arr.length - 1] = "last"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const pushNinetyDays = () => {
let arr = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 90 ; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        arr.push(far) 
     } else if (i == 90) {
        arr.push(close)
     } else {
        arr.push(i)
     } 
}
 return arr
}
```

All you had to do is check if i ==1 or 90 instead of what was in the array which was nothing. A better way would have been using the array and just setting arr[0] and arr[89].